# How to detect the presence of a battery?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery

I'm trying to automate [desktop setup](https://github.com/l0b0/root), and as part of that I'd like to install a battery monitor package *only if the machine currently has a battery attached* (UPSes and other external batteries are not relevant). How can I go about detecting this?

My laptop has a directory `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` and my desktop has nothing in the `/sys/class/power_supply` directory. Is that a rock-solid indicator on a system with [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)? The [reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt) doesn't mention `BATn` directories; are they likely a vendor-specific feature?

Answer (score 4):

The presence of battery information in `/sys/class/power_supply` is a reliable indicator that the system supports a battery, and it's a standard Linux feature, but it won't always be called the same thing. Yours is called `BAT1`. I am looking at one here that is called `battery`. Also, not all entries in `/sys/class/power_supply` are batteries.

Look for all files matching the pattern `/sys/class/power/supply/*/type`. If at least one of them contains the work `Battery`, there is a battery. Other possible values for `type` are `Mains` and `USB`, maybe more.

One other thing that is possible is that the system accepts a battery but the battery has been physically removed. In that case, the `Battery` power supply will still show up. How you can detect this *might* be system-dependent, but try reading `capacity` or something and see if you get a read error, which probably indicates that the battery has been removed.

Details: [Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt)

Comment: Could you reference a canonical document stating that `/sys/class/power_supply` is standard and will not suddenly change or a link to such a document?

Comment: @AlexejMagura Well, [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt) is right from the source, I guess.